# check mysql database if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

i want to check if a checkbox is checked through a mysql database request. 
it should be something like this (just a concept code, what of course isnt working)
that should work probably with ajax, becouse i dont want to reload all the time:

```
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT text,status FROM checkboxes where id=1 ;");

            while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<input type=\"checkbox\";
                if ({$zeile['status']} == "true") {checked=\"checked\"}\n ;
                 echo " name=\"feld\" class=\"checkIt\"/>";
                echo " {$zeile['text']}\n";
                echo "";
            }
            ?>
```

i have got 3 fields in the database. One text field where the text next to the checkbox shows up, a status field, where the script can see if something is "true" or "false" an a auto incrementation id.
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this code

```
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT text,status FROM checkboxes where id=1 ;");

while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {
    $text = "";
    $text .= "<input type=\"checkbox\"";
    if ({$zeile['status']} == "true") { $text .= " checked=\"checked\""; }
    $text .= " name=\"feld\" class=\"checkIt\"/>";
    $text .= "{$zeile['text']}";
    echo $text;
    //echo "";
}
```

There are so many errors was present in your code.

Comment: yeah... thank you. your code works perfectly! Your my man of the day ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT text,status FROM checkboxes where id=1 ;");

            while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox"';
                if ({$zeile['status']} == "true") { echo ' checked="checked"'; }
                echo ' name="feld" class="checkIt" />';
                echo $zeile['text'];
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: first. thanks for your answer, and we seems to be close to the solucion ... but i got a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in your code. any idear whats wrong here ?